# Left ideals in matrix ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Adding up to [What are the left and right ideals of matrix ring? How about the two sided ideals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26726/what-are-the-left-and-right-ideals-of-matrix-ring-how-about-the-two-sided-ideal).
Let's say that a left ideal in $M_n{R}$ is defined as the set of matrices whose rows entries are elements in a submodule $M$ of $R^n$. (The ring is commutative with neutral element.).

Why do all other left ideals have the same form as described above?

It´s been 2 days i have been handling this problem.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929378/left-ideals-of-m-nk?noredirect=1&lq=1) describes the left ideals in $M_n(K)$.

Comment: The answer there might be taken generally, right? Is not only for matrix rings over a field.

Comment: It is only over a field. But it perhaps helps to understand the other post better.