# Find all left ideals of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I am taking an introductory abstract algebra class, closely following [Gregory T. Lee's Abstract
Algebra // An Introductory Course](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-77649-1).

I have been asked to find all left, right, and two-sided ideals of the ring of $n \times n$ complex matrices, but we have not been properly introduced to ideals yet. Doing some reading ahead in the textbook (chapter 9), I think I have a decent understanding of what an ideal is but still no clue how to approach this question.

So far, I plan to use the following theorem from the textbook to state that any two-sided ideal must be the entire ring $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ if it contains an invertible matrix, so I can focus my attention on matrices with determinant $0$.

> **Theorem 9.2.** Let $R$ be a ring with identity. If an ideal $I$ of $R$ contains a unit, then $I = R$.

Next, I wanted to use something from [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929378/left-ideals-of-m-nk), but I'm afraid the textbook doesn't cover anything like this, e.g. vector spaces, until chapter 12, so I would be hesitant to use it in my solution.

There's also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26726/what-are-the-left-and-right-ideals-of-matrix-ring-how-about-the-two-sided-ideal) which seems to go into Morita equivalence which strays even further from the material in our class.

[This Wipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_ring) had some insight which I thought seemed helpful, but again, seems to reference some linear algebra concepts we haven't learned yet.

> When we view $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ as the ring of linear endomorphisms of $\mathbb{C}^n$, those matrices which vanish on a given subspace $V$ form a left ideal. Conversely, for a given left ideal $I$ of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ the intersection of null spaces of all matrices in $I$ gives a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$. Under this construction, the left ideals of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ are in bijection with the subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

The textbook itself delves into principal ideals, factor (quotient) rings, ring homomorphisms, and eventually the ring isomorphism theorems in chapter 9, all of which I feel *could* be suitable to answer this question, but it's really not clear to me how one would go about it.

Are there any ways to answer this question *without* comparing matrices in the ideals as vectors

Comment: If you are not able to use information about vector spaces them the problem is essentially impossible.

Comment: The linear algebra concepts you mention were seen in MATH2301 

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what kind of proof you are expecting. Here is an elementary one.

Suppose the left ideal (denoted by $\mathcal I$ in the sequel) is not the whole matrix space. As pointed out in a theorem that you have mentioned, the matrices in the ideal are necessarily non-units, i.e., they are singular. Let $A$ be the member of the ideal with the maximum possible rank, say, some $m<n$. If $m=0$, the ideal is clearly zero. Let us suppose that $0<m<n$.

By using elementary row and column operations (or Smith normal form, or rank factorisation), we may write $A=P(I_m\oplus 0)Q$ for some invertible matrices $P$ and $Q$. For any $1\le j\le m$, let $T$ be the permutation matrix corresponding to the transposition $(j,n)$. Then $B=(PTP^{-1})A\in\mathcal I$, and so is $A-B=P(e_j-e_n)e_j^TQ$, where $\{e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n\}$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb C^n$. For any $1\le i\le n$, take any invertible matrix $R\in M_n(\mathbb C)$ such that $R(e_j-e_n)=e_i$. Then $(PRP^{-1})(A-B)=Pe_ie_j^TQ\in\mathcal I$.

It follows that $W=\operatorname{span}\{Pe_ie_j^TQ: 1\le i\le n,\ 1\le j\le m\}\subseteq\mathcal I$. In turn, we must have $W=\mathcal I$, because for every $X\in\mathcal I\setminus W$, some member of the coset $X+V$ will have rank $>m$.

Note that $W$ can also be written as $\{M\in M_n(\mathbb C):MV=0\}$ where $V$ denotes the subspace $\operatorname{span}\{Q^{-1}e_j: j>m\}$ of $\mathbb C^n$. (This is also true when $m=0$ or $m=n$: just take $V=M_n(\mathbb C)$ or $V=0$ respectively.) This is what *“those matrices that vanish on a given subspace $V$”* in your cited passage means.